# Compare two projects using vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to compare two identical projects (with some differences) in vscode? I want to find the difference in the files (e.g. `main.c` in the first project vs `main.c` in the second project and so on recersively)

Note: The are a lot of files. I don't want to compare them one by one (by right-clicking on them and choose the `compare with` option)

Comment: Many of the Merge Tools can do this for you (WinMerge, KDiff3,....) some need to be called by the command line with the right parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unaware of VS Code doing this.  Beyond Compare does this very well.  (exactly what you are describing)

You can choose two directories.  The UI will show two columns, and in each they will be highlighted red if there are discrepancies.  You can open each folder to see what the differences are.

Answer (score 3):

There are VS Code extensions that allow you to compare entire folder structures. One of them is [Diff Folders](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=L13RARY.l13-diff), which lets you enter two paths and then generates an overview of the changes:

[image: Diff Folders]

It shows which files were added, removed or changed. By double clicking on an entry, you can see the diff for that file.